# Android java exoplayer2 проигрование с файловой системы и raw/

Tags: java, android, файлы, exoplayer

```js
package com.none.rnar.testplayer.service;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioFocusRequest;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.okhttp.OkHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.Cache;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

import com.none.rnar.testplayer.R;
import com.none.rnar.testplayer.ui.MainActivity;

import java.io.File;



final public class PlayerService extends Service {

  private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 404;
  private final String NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID = "default_channel";

  private final MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();

  private final PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder().setActions(
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP |
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
  );

  private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

  private AudioManager audioManager;
  private AudioFocusRequest audioFocusRequest;
  private boolean audioFocusRequested = false;

  private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
  private ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;
  private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;

  private final MusicRepository musicRepository = new MusicRepository();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.notification_channel_name), NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

      AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();
      audioFocusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(audioFocusChangeListener)
        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(false)
        .setWillPauseWhenDucked(true)
        .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
        .build();
    }

    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService");
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);

    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();

    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class);
    mediaSession.setSessionActivity(PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0, activityIntent, 0));

    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null, appContext, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0));

    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
    exoPlayer.addListener(exoPlayerListener);
    DataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(new OkHttpClient(), Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)), null);
    Cache cache = new SimpleCache(new File(this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/exoplayer"), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 100)); // 100 Mb max
    this.dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, httpDataSourceFactory, CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE | CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);
    this.extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaSession.release();
    exoPlayer.release();
  }

  private MediaSessionCompat.Callback mediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

    private Uri currentUri;
    int currentState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED;

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
      if (!exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady()) {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class));

        MusicRepository.Track track = musicRepository.getCurrent();
        updateMetadataFromTrack(track);

        prepareToPlay(track.getUri());

        if (!audioFocusRequested) {
          audioFocusRequested = true;

          int audioFocusResult;
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            audioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusRequest);
          } else {
            audioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
          }
          if (audioFocusResult != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
            return;
        }

        mediaSession.setActive(true); // Сразу после получения фокуса

        registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY));

        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
      }

      mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1).build());
      currentState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;

      refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      if (exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady()) {
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
      }

      mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1).build());
      currentState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;

      refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
      if (exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady()) {
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
      }

      if (audioFocusRequested) {
        audioFocusRequested = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          audioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(audioFocusRequest);
        } else {
          audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener);
        }
      }

      mediaSession.setActive(false);

      mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1).build());
      currentState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED;

      refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);

      stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
      MusicRepository.Track track = musicRepository.getNext();
      updateMetadataFromTrack(track);

      refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);

      prepareToPlay(track.getUri());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
      MusicRepository.Track track = musicRepository.getPrevious();
      updateMetadataFromTrack(track);

      refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);

      prepareToPlay(track.getUri());
    }

    private void prepareToPlay(Uri uri) {
      if (!uri.equals(currentUri)) {
        currentUri = uri;
        ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
      }
    }

    private void updateMetadataFromTrack(MusicRepository.Track track) {
      metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), track.getBitmapResId()));
      metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, track.getTitle());
      metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, track.getArtist());
      metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, track.getArtist());
      metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, track.getDuration());
      mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
    }
  };

  private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
      switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
          mediaSessionCallback.onPlay(); // Не очень красиво
          break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
          mediaSessionCallback.onPause();
          break;
        default:
          mediaSessionCallback.onPause();
          break;
      }
    }
  };

  private final BroadcastReceiver becomingNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Disconnecting headphones - stop playback
      if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        mediaSessionCallback.onPause();
      }
    }
  };

  private ExoPlayer.EventListener exoPlayerListener = new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {}

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {}

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {}

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
      if (playWhenReady && playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
        mediaSessionCallback.onSkipToNext();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {}

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {}

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {}
  };

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new PlayerServiceBinder();
  }

  public class PlayerServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MediaSessionCompat.Token getMediaSessionToken() {
      return mediaSession.getSessionToken();
    }
  }

  private void refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(int playbackState) {
    switch (playbackState) {
      case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING:
        {
          startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(playbackState));
          break;
        }
      case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED:
        {
          NotificationManagerCompat.from(PlayerService.this).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(playbackState));
          stopForeground(false);
          break;
        }
      default:
        {
          stopForeground(true);
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  private Notification getNotification(int playbackState) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(this, mediaSession);
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, getString(R.string.previous), MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)));

    if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
      builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, getString(R.string.pause), MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));
    else
      builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, getString(R.string.play), MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));

    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, getString(R.string.next), MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)));
    builder.setStyle(new MediaStyle()
      .setShowActionsInCompactView(1)
      .setShowCancelButton(true)
      .setCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
      .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())); // setMediaSession требуется для Android Wear
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)); // The whole background (in MediaStyle), not just icon background
    builder.setShowWhen(false);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID);

    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

```js
package com.none.rnar.testplayer.service;

import android.net.Uri;

import com.none.rnar.testplayer.R;


final class MusicRepository {

  private final Track[] data = {
    new Track("Triangle", "Jason Shaw", R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_big), (3 * 60 + 41) * 1000),
    new Track("Rubix Cube", "Jason Shaw", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_black), (3 * 60 + 44) * 1000),
    new Track("MC Ballad S Early Eighties", "Frank Nora", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_blue), (2 * 60 + 50) * 1000),
    new Track("Folk Song", "Brian Boyko", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_child), (3 * 60 + 5) * 1000),
    new Track("Morning Snowflake", "Kevin MacLeod", R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.saga), (2 * 60 + 0) * 1000),
  };

  private final int maxIndex = data.length - 1;
  private int currentItemIndex = 0;

  Track getNext() {
    if (currentItemIndex == maxIndex)
      currentItemIndex = 0;
    else
      currentItemIndex++;
    return getCurrent();
  }

  Track getPrevious() {
    if (currentItemIndex == 0)
      currentItemIndex = maxIndex;
    else
      currentItemIndex--;
    return getCurrent();
  }

  Track getCurrent() {
    return data[currentItemIndex];
  }

  static class Track {

    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private int bitmapResId;
    private Uri uri;
    private long duration; // in ms

    Track(String title, String artist, int bitmapResId, Uri uri, long duration) {
      this.title = title;
      this.artist = artist;
      this.bitmapResId = bitmapResId;
      this.uri = uri;
      this.duration = duration;
    }

    String getTitle() {
      return title;
    }

    String getArtist() {
      return artist;
    }

    int getBitmapResId() {
      return bitmapResId;
    }

    Uri getUri() {
      return uri;
    }

    long getDuration() {
      return duration;
    }
  }
}
```

Привет. Подскажите плиз, как добавить сюда возможность проигровать файлы с файловой системы устройства, и с папки raw. (хотя-бы укажите направление куда копать)

Попробовал просто ссылку на аудио заменить на такого вида... Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_big) . 
Но это, естественно не помогло, что и не странно. Т.к насколько я понимаю, наверное где-то okhttp3 загружает аудиозапись по сети и сохраняет его во временную память, затем exoplayer как-то это играет. К сожалению я пока не могу определить точно ту часть кода где это происходит, и как. Было бы здорово если бы указали на эти места.
Так-же не могу понять вот что`new Track("Triangle", "Jason Shaw", R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.none.rnar.testplayer/" + R.raw.us_big), (3 * 60 + 41) * 1000))`
последний параметр (duration), по названию можно догадаться что это продолжительность. Но почему она указывается в ручную, да ещё и способом умножения и сложения чисел. Зачем этот параметр здесь? В таком виде...
p.s

---

И если можно, ссылочку на примеры реализации различных плюшек от гугла, с этими либами (которые на java и актуальны) ибо я чука потерялся (первый раз работю с android). 
Спасибо! И да, простите за глупый вопрос, просто уже почти день мучаюсь с этим примером, что весьма и весьма печально =)
Вот где я взял этот пример [>>тык<<](https://habr.com/post/339416/)

Comment: Актуален только вопрос о "duration" и его возможном предназначении ...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем нужно было всеголишь

```js
DataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(new OkHttpClient(), Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)), null);
```

заменить на

```js
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new FileDataSourceFactory();
```

ну и путь заменил на такого рода Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/MyData/sagаobegile")
Если вдруг кому пригодится...